# Can't get the bootstrap navbar to show the toggle button when sizing to smaller resolution

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The navbar looks fine until resizing to a smaller resolution. When doing this, all the nav items disappear and the "hamburger icon" does not actually show up.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-md fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/home">
      <img src="images/girlsinthegame.png" width="10%"/>
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mydropdown">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mydropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/badgeInformation">Information</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/leaderboard">Leaderboard</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Add  `navbar-light` to navbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is button in **right side** but you are not given color button. so white color. Add `navbar-light` to become more visible.

**Your Demo with code** - *click right top side*

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-md fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/home">
      <img src="https://www.girlsinthegame.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/GIG_25th_Logo-Clear-BG71128.png" height="50px"/>
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mydropdown">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mydropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/badgeInformation">Information</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/leaderboard">Leaderboard</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Solution Fixed**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/home">
      <img src="https://www.girlsinthegame.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/GIG_25th_Logo-Clear-BG71128.png" height="50px"/>
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mydropdown">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mydropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/badgeInformation">Information</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/leaderboard">Leaderboard</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I Hope this works perfectly. @Albert Vu , If any changes i would happy to change the answer too :). If the answer worked correclty don't forgot [to accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).